# Applescript to select a highlight color in Preview

Tags: macos, applescript, keyboard-shortcuts, toolbar

I've recently found Applescript after desperate hours trying to figure out a way to do the trick since I use Preview A LOT. The button to open highlighting colors doesn't have any menu item or keyboard shortcut (only for general highlight that is yellow, my plan was to create shortcuts for the rest of the colors available), it's only located in the toolbar. The code I've encountered for similar problems didn't work (probably due to my serious lack of knowledge in the area...), so if anyone could come up with something I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd like to make note that **Preview** does not contain an **AppleScript** *dictionary file*, e.g. **Preview.sdef**, and as such, sans a minimal set of *default commands*, is not easily scriptable beyond the *default commands* and requires **UI Scripting** with **System Events** to achieve the goal.

Note that **UI Scripting** can be kludgy and has its own issues and requires granting privileges in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility**, which one should be prompted for if necessary, however I present two options for your consideration.

---

**Option 1**

This first option simply triggers the **Highlight** *menu* where you can then press the *key* of the first character of a *color*, after which you press the <kbd>enter</kbd> to set the chosen *color*. For the *color* **Purple**, since there is also **Pink**, pressing <kbd>P</kbd> will of course highlight **Pink**, so pressing <kbd>P</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> will select **Purple**. You can also use the **Up/Down** *arrow keys* to navigate the *menu*.

This would allow you to actuate the *menu* with one assigned *keyboard shortcut* and not have to explicitly assign a *keyboard shortcut* for each individual *color*.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Preview" to activate
delay 0.1
tell application "System Events"
    tell group 2 of ¬
        toolbar 1 of ¬
        window 1 of ¬
        application process "Preview"
        
        try
            click menu button 1 of group 1
        on error
            click menu button 1 of radio group 1
        end try
        
    end tell
end tell
```

<sup>**Note:** In the *example* **AppleScript** *code* shown above make note that there is an `try` *statement* with *error handling* to click the target *menu*. This is because the *hierarchical UI element structure* changes based on whether or not *highlighting* has already been used in the current *document*. This also allows for the *script* to silently fail if the *keyboard shortcut* to trigger it is pressed on a *document* that *highlighting* cannot be preformed on.</sup>

---

**Option 2**

This next option presents a *list* to choose from and then sets the *highlight color* based on the selection.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
set colorList to ¬
    {"Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Pink", "Purple"}

set chosenHighlightColor to ¬
    (choose from list colorList ¬
        with title "Select Highlight Color") ¬
        as string

if chosenHighlightColor is "false" then return

tell application "Preview" to activate

tell application "System Events"
    tell group 2 of ¬
        toolbar 1 of ¬
        window 1 of ¬
        application process "Preview"
        
        try
            click menu button 1 of group 1
        on error
            click menu button 1 of radio group 1
        end try
        delay 0.05
        try
            click menu item chosenHighlightColor of menu 1
        end try
        
    end tell
end tell
```

<sup>**Note:** In the *example* **AppleScript** *code* shown above make note that there is an `try` *statement* with *error handling* to click the target *menu*. This is because the *hierarchical UI element structure* changes based on whether or not *highlighting* has already been used in the current *document*. This also allows for the *script* to silently fail if the *keyboard shortcut* to trigger it is pressed on a *document* that *highlighting* cannot be preformed on.</sup>

---

**Automator** *Service/Quick Action* and **Keyboard Shortcut**

To use either of these *examples* as a *keyboard shortcut*, create an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* with a **Run Shell Script** *action* replacing the *default code* with the *example* **AppleScript** *code*.

Then in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** assign it a *keyboard shortcut*. I used **⇧⌘H** as it was not already assigned to anything in **Preview**.

---

**Notes**:

- This was tested and worked for me as is under **macOS Catalina** and **macOS Big Sur** with **Language & Region** setting in **System Preferences** set to **English US**.
- Does not work if the *document* is in **Full Screen** view.

---

**Select Highlight Color**

[image]

---

**Automator** *Service/Quick Action*

[image]

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply! I tried both of them but the same error appeared: The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “System Events got an error: Can’t get radio group 1 of group 2 of toolbar 1 of window 1 of application process "Preview". Invalid index.”

Comment: I'm in Big Sur and set the language to English to see if it worked but got the same message. In the first I can reach the menu to select the color but once I choose one the message appears.

Comment: IT WORKED! It made to my mind that the order in which the button was in your toolbar could be different from mine, so I put mine in 2nd as you wrote and it worked - the only problem is that it only works when it's not in fullscreen, is there anything that could be done for that?

Comment: @Felix, RE: "the only problem is that it only works when it's not in fullscreen" --  That is one of the issues with **UI Scripting**. RE: "is there anything that could be done for that?" --  Yes, but it's very kludgy as it would have to be coded to temporarily show the   **menu bar/toolbar**, if it could be made to work under that scenario.  I have never tried, but will update the answer if I can make it work.

Comment: I ticked the "Always show toolbar" and it didn't work as well, the message that displays is - Can’t get toolbar 1 of window 1 of application process "Preview". Invalid index. - don't know if it helps. But still, thank you so much for the work you had, it already helped me a lot!

Comment: @Felix, I done a bit of testing and while I was able to get the first option working in **Full Screen** view using a _third-party utility_, nonetheless, it was very kludgy and unreliable. For this reason, the note I added under **Notes**: "Does not work if the _document_ is in **Full Screen** view." after you first mentioned it stands and I will not publish the kludgy and unreliable _code_, sorry.

Comment: If anyone ever gets to this question you can make it work in Full Screen by adding a line with "group 1 of ¬" between "toolbar 1 of ¬" and "window 1 of ¬", hope it works for you too!